# Python filter a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

Newbie so please be gentle.

I have a selenium script which generates a har file, code is as follows:

```
proxy.har  # returns a HAR
for ent in proxy.har['log']['entries']:
    _url = ent['request']['headers']
    _response = ent['response']
    #print(ent)
    for item in ent['request']['headers']:
        print(item)
```

Here is the output:

```
{'value': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ Safari/', 'name': 'User-Agent'}
{'value': 'application/json', 'name': 'content-type'}
{'value': '8d14747f41e552da0076374b6646b1d309763357195e2ec5b6be6da1d12dcf6801113', 'name': 'a-security-token'}
{'value': '8e9720fcead251fafd2c215443e3c6e7555667990f00bcfad70127e340048eb901113', 'name': 'ccu'}
{'value': 'isAjax:true', 'name': 'ADRUM'}
{'value': '*/*', 'name': 'Accept'}
```

I want to filter out the a-security token value and the ccu value. I have tried using lambda, but it just prints nothings here is my lambda code:

```
filtered_item = filter(lambda d: 'ccu' in d , item)
for d in filtered_item:
   print(d)
```

O

Comment: `in` only checks keys of dictionaries, not values. You'll need to do something like `d['name'] == 'ccu'` instead of `in`. I'd post an answer, but I don't know enough about the data format to know if this will always work.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think that it is quite poor formatting for headers to have a list of dicts, and before further manipulation, I would turn it into a proper python dict.
For example:

```
headers = {e['name']: e['value'] for e in ent['request']['headers']}
```

which gives:

```
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ Safari/', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'a-security-token': '8d14747f41e552da0076374b6646b1d309763357195e2ec5b6be6da1d12dcf6801113', 'ccu': '8e9720fcead251fafd2c215443e3c6e7555667990f00bcfad70127e340048eb901113', 'ADRUM': 'isAjax:true', 'Accept': '*/*'}
```

Then it is easy to get any header from this list:

```
>>> headers['ccu']
'8e9720fcead251fafd2c215443e3c6e7555667990f00bcfad70127e340048eb901113'
>>> headers['a-security-token']
'8d14747f41e552da0076374b6646b1d309763357195e2ec5b6be6da1d12dcf6801113'
```

Easy to read and manipulate.

Comment: I like this answer, but it didn't quite work, I get keyerror when doing print(headers['ccu'])

Comment: I based my answer on your output, but not having access to the base data I can’t really elaborate. With the output you gave I formed a list of dicts and parsed it with my code which gives the wanted values. Can you provide ent['request']['headers'] and subsequent parsed headers?

Comment: Updated the post with the output. Thanks for your help brother

Comment: There must be a difference with what you previously retrieved because in the whole output there is no 'ccu' anymore.

Comment: Its cst that I am interested in

Answer (score 0):

The following list comprehension should get you a list of all `values` that match your criteria:

```
filtered_items = [d['value'] for d in har_list if d['name'] in ['a-security-token', 'ccu']]
```

However, if these items will only appear once each in the list, and you want to get them separately, you can use the `next` method, which will also ensure the code doesn't break in case the data is not found:

```
a_sec_token = next((d['value'] for d in har_list if d['name'] == 'a-security-token'), None)
ccu = next((d['value'] for d in har_list if d['name'] == 'ccu'), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# function that filters rows given string
def get_item(row):
    string_to_compare='ccu'
    if(row['name'] == string_to_compare):
        return True
    else:
        return False

filtered_item = filter(get_item, item)

print('The filtered items are:')
for filt_item in filtered_item:
    print(filt_item)
```